# Is WinDbg's vertarget command always accurate?

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

I wonder because running it on a client's minidump it reports a different Windows version than the client repeatedly told me she had, and the version I'm being reported happens to be exactly the same version I'm running WinDbg on.

So I wonder, can vertarget always be trusted (and clients not) or the information it relies on may be absent with some dump generation options and when it is it reports the version WinDbg is currently running on, or maybe just some default that happens to coincide with my OS version?

I'm using WinDbg 6.12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all my cases so far, `vertarget` has been correct and the customer/client made a mistake - and `vertarget` is one of the commands I use for every dump, exactly for the purpose of checking if the dump contains what I need.

But perhaps, things can potentially go wrong here as well, so let's evaluate some options:

1. `vertarget` also reports debug session time and system uptime. Do those also match your system? Reboot your system in order to get a low system uptime and check again. Is it still your PC's uptime?
2. `vertarget` also reports the number of CPUs. Does that number match your number?
3. Get a virtual machine which does not have your OS, e.g. one from [Modern.IE (Microsoft)](https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/). Copy WinDbg and the dump to the VM and check the output of `vertarget` again.
4. WinDbg [6.12 is a bit old](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/). Do newer versions (6.2.9200 / 6.3.9600 or even 10.0) provide the same information or was there a bug fixed already?

And even check some other information:

1. Is it a dump of the correct application? Use `|` (pipe)
2. Is it a dump of the version you are expecting? Use `lm vm <exename>`
3. Does it have the flags which can be expected for the method used for taking the dump? Use `.dumpdebug`.

Other than that I observe (not representative) that many client OS version dumps (Windows 7, 8, 8.1) have all latest service packs installed, while administrators seem to follow the "never change a running system" approach for server OS (Windows Server 2012, R2). So it might just be a coincident.

Comment: `.dumpdebug` seems to be present on my windbg 10.0.10240.9 (64-bit). Either way, with [DumpChk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542776(v=vs.85).aspx) one can get the same information.

Comment: @Donpedro: thanks. It was my fault: I tried to use it in a live session.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, I kind of forgot of this.
At the end I indeed verified that the information was correct (I tried it on another machine).

Notes to your points:
1. The system time on user-mode dumps seems to be only present in full-memory dumps

Comment: 4. Thanks, nice to know :)  And great blog post. I actually even did have a more recent version installed, but I forgot to update the shortcuts :D . By the way, do you happen to know what's the last version working with Windows XP? The 6.3.9600 definitely doesn't, but it doesn't seem to be the case either that it be the one included in the WDK 7.1.0, as Microsoft says, that is mine 6.12.2.633: I have a more recent 6.2.8400.0 that seems to work. I can't find anything about that on the web.

Comment: 3. I wasn't aware of .dumpdebug (it's not mentioned anywhere in the help file!), very nice command.

Comment: @gbr: regarding WinDbg on XP: in most cases it's only the installation that does not work. Once installed on any machine, you can just copy the installation directory. E.g. you can't install, but you can run WinDbg 10.0 on Windows 7. But no, I have not tested which versions work on which OS or not. Would indeed be a nice addition to that list.

Comment: @gbr: 6.2.9200.16384 seems to run on XP, 6.3.9600.16384 doesn't

Comment: Thank you. BTW, for your list, the version 6.2.8400.0 was included in the "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8 Release Preview"